# npm install -g firebase-tools causing errors

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nvm, firebase-cli

I am trying to run: `npm install -g firebase-tools` on my terminal inorder to work with firebase functions.

**But when I do so I get the following error output:**

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/myusername/.npm/_logs/2019-05-21T19_11_21_252Z-debug.log
```

I have been going through this. And their recommended things to do, but I am . either misunderstanding the instructions or they are just not working.

What I am doing:

- Running: `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash`
- then: `command -v nvm` which sometimes returns nothing and other times returns `nvm` Even when this is the case however running firebases line fails

**How do I solve this?**

Comment: It looks like you haven't install nvm correctly, as it's not putting `node` in your path ahead of the system's `node`.  You can tell it's still trying to use the system node, since you see /usr/local in the location it's trying to access.

Comment: Is the first bullet not how it's done? Guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've not had a problem following the documentation.  I don't think there's anything left unsaid there.

Comment: @DougStevenson see update

Comment: If you have an answer to your own question, you can just answer it as you would normally.  Don't edit the question with the answer, as that leaves the question formally unanswered on Stack Overflow, and is less likely to help others in the future.

Comment: Understood, @DougStevenson but I do have one error and so I would hope to have an answer to that, and then I would have a full answer I can share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**: I solved this issue work by following: https://www.codementor.io/mercurial/how-to-install-node-js-on-macos-sierra-mphz41ekk

Answer (score -1):

exp version 11.0.0 for

- npm i firebase-tools@11.0.0

Comment: Sarac I think this question is more specific to an issue happening in that user's machine due to permissions issue. This is more of a generic answer to `how to install firebase-tools` globally. So this doesn't answer the question